# Updating text link URL in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a link in the tooltip of a line chart in d3. 
Similar to [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569).

The link will be an attribute of the data so I want to be able to change the link, as the tooltip focuses over different parts of the data.

I am not using a div because I want to have a responsive page, and don't want to use absolute positioning.

I can't figure out how to change the link after it had been set.
So, far I have just tried calling:

```
  .attr("xlink:href", 'http://www.yahoo.com')
```

a second time, but this does not update it.

A jsfiddle example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fLrf9okb/).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the href to text DOM so instead of this:

```
 d3.select('.tlink') //it will give you the text DOM
     .attr("xlink:href", 'http://www.yahoo.com') //< link does not change?
     .style('fill', 'red');
```

Do this:

```
 d3.select('a')//select anchor 
     .attr("xlink:href", 'http://www.yahoo.com') //< link does not change?
     .style('fill', 'red');
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wuzn4kez/)